# Serealized mode in System.Data.SQLite for .NET

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am working on a .NET application that uses the SQLite. As per SQLite [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html), it supports multi-threading and can be used in one of following 3 modes

1. Single-thread. In this mode, all mutexes are disabled and SQLite is unsafe to use in more than a single thread at once.
2. Multi-thread. In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads provided that no single database connection is used simultaneously in two or more threads.
3. Serialized. In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads with no restriction.

As per these modes, I am trying to use the Serialized where I am sharing the Single connection across multiple Tasks. But I get the error as "**Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.**"

I guess this is due to the sharing of single connection across tasks. But As per the Serialized mode I should be able to share the connection without doing any explicit locking or mutex implementation. 
***Can any one please guide me how I can use the Serialized mode in .net application ?*** Does it requires connection string to be mentioned in certain way ?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Just use one connection per thread.

Comment: But that will be  "Multi-thread" threading mode. I don't want to create connection every time I talk to SqliteDB hence going for "Serialized" threading mode.

Comment: @CL.
Does System.Data.SQLite really supports "Serialized" threading mode ?

Comment: Hi @DDeshmane did you find how to turn on the Serialized mode? (I'm searching for the same thing...)

Answer (score 1):

Serialized is the default mode. Do not close open connection again instead yse the same single connection every where without need of closing it. SQLite will take care of rest. Hope this helps.